# Request of references to solve a problem in analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I would like to know knowledge of what topics or references I need to solve this problem in analytic number theory [image]

I have learned analysis and first year undergraduate number theory.

---

We have $1 * \Lambda (n) = \log n$,

where * is multiplicative convolution,  $f * g (n) = \sum_{ab=n} f(a)g(b), 1(n)=1, \Lambda$ is Mangoldt function.

then with
$1*f=g$ iff $\mu *g = f$  (theorem 1)

we can deduce that $\log * \mu(n) = \Lambda (n)$ (eq 2)

where $\mu$ is Möbius function.

I hope to know any hint of the way to prove (eq 2) without using (theorem 1).

Comment: You will need basic analytic number theory covered in the lectures before. Please don't use pictures of text or formulas.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you. How ‘basic’? Would you like to suggest a lecture note?

Comment: I ask because the lecture note given about the problem has not mentioned textbooks and the note is not very comprehensive. So I would like to know relevant textbooks or lecture notes **suggesting references **, so I can study the books or notes by myself

Comment: Yes, there is a student mathematical library booklet volume 6 "*The Prime Numbers and their Distribution*" by Gerald Tenenbaum and Michael Mendes France. It is short and concise.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: A standard reference is Montgomery's "Multiplicative Number Theory". It is very comprehensive, but if you look at the chapter on the prime number theorrm, and look back whenever needed, it might suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: In Montgomery, with the use of the large sieve, it is shown that $$\pi(x)-\pi (x-y)\le \frac{2y}{\log(y)}$$ for $1<y\le x$.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim: "Multiplicative Number Theory" has two authors—please don't omit Vaughan when citing it. (Probably applies to Dietrich Burde's comment as well.)

Comment: Apologies, pulled it from memory, so definitely room for error. Thanks for the correction.